# movieclip in textfield's text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've a text-field into that I have to add small text which is inside a movieclip. So finally it becomes.

`text part1` + `movieclip` + `text Part2`

I want `text part1` and `text part2` to be single textfield. So that when I remove/delete movieclip between them the text can be continuous. Can it be done in flash with Actionscript 3.0??

NOTE : I am not talking about text inside movieclip. I want small movieclip to be fit among textfield. just like the image can be set to be inside text in any Word-processor program.

Answer (score 1):

`TextField.htmlText` and `<img src='filename'/>` should do the trick though it offers few options as to formatting.  Depends on the size of the picture really but used like:

`textField.htmlText = "Example text" + <img src='pic.jpg'/> + "example text.";`

..will insert the picture in the middle of the string.

Update: This can be used to insert a movie clip in line with a textfield using the movie clips linkage identifier:

`textField.htmlText = "Example text" + <img src='myMC'/> + "example text.";`

More info (and examples) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText
[Load MovieClip inline in TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766957/load-movieclip-inline-in-textfield)

Comment: Actually I wanted small movieclips to go between text. Any way to do it??

Comment: I edited the Question. It was not showing some text which i did put between angles <

Comment: The same concept still applies, just use the linkage identifier for the movieclip: <img src='movieClip'/>.

Comment: Any working example of the thing stated above with textField.htmlText ?? I tried but it did not work for me :( It just places a copy of movieClip below the textField doing what said above.

Comment: Plz help installing http://www.doitflash.com people's textarea component also. I think it does somewhat similar task. But I dont know where to put their as3 class files. :(